# how to call the function in view file in cakephp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i want to call the javascript function in view file in input field, how can I do that?

```
 <script>
  function new(){
  // code
 }
 </script>

<?php echo $this->FormManager->input('search',array('label'=>'Search'));?>
```

I wan to call function in this input field, how can I do that?

Any one can help? thanks in advance

Comment: It may not be related to the question, but you cannot use "new" as a name for your function, since it is a reserved keyword in javascript.

Comment: @VanCoding I just give an example bro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add and ID to that input and bind `focus` event:

```
<?php echo $this->FormManager->input('search',array('label'=>'Search', 'id'=>'searchBtn'));?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchBtn').on('focus', function(){
        // your function
    });
});
</script>
```

Every time that input it's `focus`ed or whatever you want, that function is called.

Comment: But can you find the function to and input event?